# Some CommonModule directives not functioning on nested module

Tags: angular

I have a module (module A) with a component in it that is trying to use ngClass. Running this module in isolation (with storybook for example) it works fine.

I an app that imports moduleA into a global module which exports moduleA. I then have moduleB which is lazy loaded and imports the global module. So far so good. Now i I try and use the component in moduleA and the page explodes with

```
Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgClass -> KeyValueDiffers]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgClass -> KeyValueDiffers]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for KeyValueDiffers!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgClass -> KeyValueDiffers]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgClass -> KeyValueDiffers]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for KeyValueDiffers!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (VM17950 vendor.js:39808)
    at resolveToken (VM17950 vendor.js:40046)
    at tryResolveToken (VM17950 vendor.js:39990)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (VM17950 vendor.js:39887)
    at resolveToken (VM17950 vendor.js:40046)
    at tryResolveToken (VM17950 vendor.js:39990)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (VM17950 vendor.js:39887)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (VM17950 vendor.js:47125)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (VM17950 vendor.js:47813)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (VM17950 vendor.js:47125)
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (VM17950 vendor.js:39808)
    at resolveToken (VM17950 vendor.js:40046)
    at tryResolveToken (VM17950 vendor.js:39990)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (VM17950 vendor.js:39887)
    at resolveToken (VM17950 vendor.js:40046)
    at tryResolveToken (VM17950 vendor.js:39990)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (VM17950 vendor.js:39887)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (VM17950 vendor.js:47125)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (VM17950 vendor.js:47813)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (VM17950 vendor.js:47125)
    at resolvePromise (VM17944 polyfills.js:7582)
    at resolvePromise (VM17944 polyfills.js:7539)
    at VM17944 polyfills.js:7641
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (VM17944 polyfills.js:7189)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (VM17950 vendor.js:42564)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (VM17944 polyfills.js:7188)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (VM17944 polyfills.js:6956)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (VM17944 polyfills.js:7363)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (VM17944 polyfills.js:7268)
    at invokeTask (VM17944 polyfills.js:8308)
```

If i remove the ngClass reference from the component in moduleA the error goes away. Searching for "No provider for KeyValueDiffers" yields practically nothing.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    GlobalModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule { }



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ModalModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    ModalModule
  ]
})
export class GlobalModule {}
```

This module is lazily loaded:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SettingsRoutingModule,
    GlobalModule
  ],
  declarations: [
  ]
})
export class SettingsModule { }
```

This is the module with the component that I am trying to use in SettingsModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ModalComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [
    ModalComponent
  ]
})
export class ModalModule { }
```

I don't have a problem using ngClass anywhere else such as a component defined and declared withing SettingsModule.

Comment: what is the globalmodule? the reason you cant use ngClass in the setting module is because you didnt import it

Comment: GlobalModule is a module that holds all the imports shared between the app module and lazily loaded modules. GlobalModule imports (and exports) CommonModule which provides ngClass. SettingsModule imports CommonModule so it therefore imports CommonModule as well. The error I have is not that ngClass is not recognized, rathers its a dependency of ngClass that cannot be found (KeyValueDiffers).

Comment: but you dont import commonmodule, thats what im trying to tell you. if you add it, it will start working

Comment: into SettingsModule you mean? (its imported in every other module)

Comment: you need to import it into the settingsmodule and possible also the appmodule (cant remember if its required in the appmodule) so it shares any modules imported

Comment: Adding CommonModule to SettingsModule didn't change things. I would expect anything that is exported by GlobalModule to be implicitly imported into SettingsModule when I import GlobalModule.

Answer (score 0):

Problem related to a rogue node_modules folder somewhere down the directory hierarchy causing multiple loads of angular files which seems to have confused it.